# Using Cauchy's theorem or Integral formula to evaluate $\oint_C \frac{\sin2z}{6z-\pi} dz,$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I have the problem, to use Cauchy's theorem or Cauchy's integral formula to evaluate $\oint_C \dfrac{\sin2z}{6z-\pi} dz$, where $C$ is the circle $\mod (z) = 3$.

I know that the denominator vanishes at z =  $\dfrac{\pi}{6}$, which is within the contour, so the result of the integral is not $0$ (Cauchy's theorem). I have a singularity within the contour, then, and it is not analytic. How then can I use Cauchy's theorem or integral formula for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for the residue theorem, Cauchy's integral formula gives the answer right away:

$$
\oint_C \dfrac{\sin2z}{6z-\pi}\,dz =
\oint_C \dfrac{\frac{\sin2z}{6}}{z-\frac{\pi}{6}}\,dz = 2\pi i\,\frac{\sin \frac{\pi}3}{6} = \frac{\pi i\sqrt{3}}{6}.
$$

Comment: how does Cauchy's integral formula give this?

Comment: @user1535776 Which step is unclear?

Comment: Why does $(z - \dfrac{\pi}{6})$ go away, and how does $2 \pi i$ come about? It looks like residue theorem, how did you get it from Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: @user1535776 Cauchy's integral formula says that $$\oint_C \frac{f(z)}{z-a}\,dz = 2\pi i f(a)$$ if $f$ is analytic on and inside $C$. Here $a=\pi/6$ and $f(z)=\frac16 \sin 2z$.

Comment: Okay, perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Apply the [Residue Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).  The integral has a singularity at $z=\frac{\pi}{6}$, which is inside the disk, so the value is $$2\pi i \text{Res} \left(\frac{1}{6}\frac{\sin (2z)}{z-\pi/6},\ z=\frac{\pi}{6}\right).$$

This will equal $$\frac{\pi i}{3}\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)= \frac{\pi i}{2\sqrt{3}}.$$

Comment: Don't know why I missed that, perfect